# Linux how to convert time format to epoch time?

Tags: linux

I have the following time format: 2019-03-08T17:35:44Z

How can I convert that, using nothing but Linux commands, to epoch time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
date -d "2019-03-08T17:35:44Z" +%s
1552066544
```

To get the current epoch time:

```
date +%s
1552085639
```

Comment: Please abstain from answering obvious duplicate questions. Thanks.